# Why the Alice epigraph in the epilogue of Watership Down?

Tags: intertextuality, richard-adams, watership-down, through-the-looking-glass

Each chapter of *Watership Down* bears an epigraph, a quote from some other source which is relevant to the chapter at hand. In the epilogue (and nowhere else?) there are *two* epigraphs, one from Shakespeare's *All's Well that Ends Well* whose relevance is clear, and one from Lewis Carroll's *Through the Looking-Glass*:

> He was part of my dream, of course -- but then I was part of his dream, too.

In *Through the Looking-Glass*, this refers to the [Red King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_King_(Through_the_Looking-Glass)), who sleeps throughout the chess game and is said to be dreaming of Alice even while she is dreaming of him, creating a cyclical paradox. What is the relevance of this paradox to *Watership Down* or its epilogue?

Comment: An obvious connection that you don't mention, is that the quotation appears right at the end of "Through the Looking-Glass".

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but I think it may have something to do with that the myths of El-Ahrairah become intertwined with Hazel’s reality and his death.
I'm not sure of its exact meaning but I love how it keeps you guessing its meaning.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please explain in words how "the myths of El-Ahrairah become intertwined with Hazel’s reality and his death" relates to the paradox in the question. (Also, the rest of your answer doesn't contribute information; please make your answers to-the-point)